# XCode. How to automatically build and "Upload to App Store" iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

To upload my iOS project to iTunesConnect I must do next steps:

1. Build project for Generic iOS Device. In XCode
2. Press button "Upload to App Store". In Organizer
3. Choose Development Team for publishing. This team exists in info.plist
4. Enable/disable checkboxes: "Include app symbols for your app..."
5. Press button "Upload"

---

Is there way for make all this steps in one command? Like:

```
$ project build_and_send_to_AppStore
```

Comment: check https://fastlane.tools

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

With help of the CI you could automate delivery of the build to the customers and iTunesConnect.

But with Apple iTunesConnect is small issue there is no clear API for this.
So there are a bunch of workarounds that are written in Ruby. But thay would like to know you're login and password to be able to deliver app to `iTunesConnect` be careful with this.

My preferred tools of CI are `Bitrise` and `Travis`. they are quite easy to use and customize.